# AsyncHttpClient onFailure method doesn't shows up a toast when an authentication is wrong

Tags: android

Using `AsyncHttpClient` I send via my Android device simple GET request to my server. My server needs an authentication. When I pass correct login and password it displays what should be displayed. Also, when an authentication is correct but there's no such a value in my database and there is 404 returned, it shows a TOAST. This code looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {

    if (statusCode == 401) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wrong authentication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (statusCode == 404) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No content", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (statusCode == 500) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There's something wrong with a server!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), throwable.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I also want to show a TOAST when an authentication is wrong. However, when 401 status code is returned, a TOAST doesn't show up. Here's my exception from android studio:

```
W/JsonHttpRH: onFailure(int, Header[], String, Throwable) was not overriden, but callback was received
              cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.HttpResponseException: UNAUTHORIZED
                  at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.sendResponseMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:446)
                  at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:160)
                  at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:177)
                  at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:106)
                  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

What may cause this problem? Thanks

EDIT:

Here are logs when content is "not found" but authorization is correct. Unfortunately, below logs doesn't appear. Btw, my TOAST doesn't appear in my application...

```
Log.d("Failed: ", "" + statusCode);
Log.d("Error : ", "" + throwable);
```

[image]

Here are logs when authorization is wrong. Below logs appear. Btw, my TOAST also appears in my application...

```
Log.d("Failed: ", "" + statusCode);
Log.d("Error : ", "" + throwable);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try with following correct method to override,

```
@Override
 public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
        super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
        Log.d("Failed: ", ""+statusCode);
        Log.d("Error : ", "" + throwable);
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't even log anything.. it just throws an exception as above

Comment: I really don't get it.. now with `super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);` it shows "wrong authentication".. however, there doesn't show up "no content" toast anymore..

Comment: Can you post new log here, print one log with status code also and see what you get.